# jQuery Plugin Scope with setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, timer

I'm working on writing a custom countdown timer in jQuery and I'm trying to write it as a plugin. I wrote the plugin based on code from http://jqueryboilerplate.com/ and https://github.com/zenorocha/jquery-plugin-patterns/ but I'm running into a scope issue.

Here's my code for the countdown:

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {
var pluginName = "countdown",
    defaults = {
        year: "",
        month: "",
        day: "",
        labels: true,
        includeMS: true
    },
    times = {
        ms: 0,
        sec: 0,
        min: 0,
        hr: 0,
        day: 0
    };

function Countdown( element, options ) {
    this.element = element;

    this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );

    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = pluginName;

    this._times = times; // I wonder if this will cause multiple timers to fail.

    this.init();
}

Countdown.prototype = {

    init: function() {
        $container = $(document.createElement('div')).addClass('rd_countdown_container').append(
            $('<span class="days countdown_time"></span> <span class="day_label countdown_label">Days</span> <span class="hours countdown_time"></span> <span class="hour_label countdown_label">Hours</span><span class="minutes countdown_time"></span> <span class="minute_label countdown_label">Minutes</span><span class="seconds countdown_time"></span> <span class="second_label countdown_label">Seconds</span><span class="ms countdown_time"></span> <span class="ms_label countdown_label">ms</span>')
            );
        if(this.options.labels === false) { $container.children('.countdown_label').hide(); }
        if(this.options.includeMS === false) { $container.children('.ms, .ms_label').hide(); }
        $(this.element).html($container);
        this.options.endDate = new Date(this.options.year, this.options.month - 1, this.options.day);
        this.intervalTimer = setInterval(this._updateCountdown, 88);
    },

    _updateCountdown: function(e) {
        var x = 0;
        var ms = this.options.endDate - new Date();
        x = this._times.ms / 1000;
        var sec = Math.floor(x % 60);
        x = x / 60;
        var min = Math.floor(x % 60);
        x = x / 60;
        var hr = Math.floor(x % 24);
        var day = Math.floor(x / 24);

        $('.rd_countdown_container .days').text(day);
        $('.rd_countdown_container .hours').text(hr);
        $('.rd_countdown_container .minutes').text(min);
        $('.rd_countdown_container .seconds').text(sec);
        $('.rd_countdown_container .ms').text(this._pad(ms % 1000, 3));
    },

    _pad: function(num, size) {
      var s = "000000000" + num;
      return s.substr(s.length-size);
    },

    stop: function() {
        console.log("Testing stop");
        clearInterval(this.intervalTimer);
    }
};

$.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
    var args = arguments;
    if (options === undefined || typeof options === 'object') {
        return this.each(function () {
            if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
                $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, new Countdown( this, options ));
            }
        });
    } else if (typeof options === 'string' && options[0] !== '_' && options !== 'init') {
        return this.each(function () {
            var instance = $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName);
            if (instance instanceof Plugin && typeof instance[options] === 'function') {
                instance[options].apply( instance, Array.prototype.slice.call( args, 1 ) );
            }
        });
    }
};
})( jQuery, window, document );
```

If I'm understanding the boilerplate correctly, all of the plugin settings are stored in the objects that are instantiated in the DOM on the page.

The problem I'm running into is that the function called in `setInterval` doesn't have access to the rest of the plugin object so it can't actually get the `endDate` to calculate the time differential. Also, when I call `$('.countdown').countdown('stop')`, it doesn't clear the `setInterval` function.

So, is there a pattern in jQuery plugins that I'm missing or just overlooking something very basic? Also, any suggestions about increasing performance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When setInterval calls `_updateCountdown` the scope is the `window`, not the instance of the countdown plugin. In order for `_updateCountdown` to have access to the rest of the plugin, you need to proxy the call like this:

```
setInterval($.proxy(this._updateCountdown, this), 88);
```